# PHP Fatal error: Duplicate type false is redundant in PHP 8.1

Tags: php, function, types, duplicates

A PHP fatal error has occurred in php 8.1 with the above php error message for the following section of code. Would anyone have any suggestions on what part could be changed to eliminate the above error?

```
static public function arrayToQueryString(array $data, $delimiter = '&', bool|false $urlencoded = false)
{
    $queryString = '';
    $delimiterLength = strlen($delimiter);

    // Parse each value pairs and concate to query string
    foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
        // Apply urlencode if it is required
        if ($urlencoded) {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $queryString .= $name . '=' . $value . $delimiter;
    }

    // remove the last delimiter
    return substr($queryString, 0, -1 * $delimiterLength);
}
```

Comment: The error message is crystal clear: having  bool|false as a type declaration is redundant

Comment: I know that. It how to change the code to eliminate the error issue that's the problem! New to php by the way.

Comment: also, there is http_build_query() that must be used instead of that homebrewed function

Comment: Why not change `bool|false`  to `bool`?

Comment: Thanks Nico. Doing your suggestion triggers the following error message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected variable "$urlencoded"

Comment: _"Doing your suggestion triggers the following error message"_ - Then you can't have done what Nico suggested, removing `|false` so it's just `, bool $urlencoded = false)`. Unless you get that error somewhere else.

Comment: If you are facing any new problem, share your attempts to resolve the initial problem first

Comment: Thanks everyone. The above worked. Just needed to fix another error in another php file, and after doing that, the above suggestion has worked. Thanks everyone for your help and input today. It's really appreciated. Still relatively new to php, and still learning, but appreciate everyone's help and time today!